# Generating content diffs using SequenceMatcher (Python)

Tags: python, diff

I want to generate a diff between to revisions of text (more specifically, Markdown-formatted articles) in Python.

I want to format this diff in a manner similar to what [Github](http://www.github.com/) does.

I've looked at `difflib` and have found that it does what I want. However, the `Differ` class is too high-level; I would have to parse the diff lines to generate HTML with inline diffs. The `Differ` class uses the `SequenceMatcher` class to generate its diffs. But looking at the `SequenceMatcher` it's very low-level in comparison. I haven't even figured out how to do a line-by-line diff (I'll admit I haven't spent a lot of time experimenting).

Does anyone know of any resources for using the `SequenceMatcher` class (besides [the `difflib` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html))?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SequenceMatcher is actually not that low-level. The most interesting method for you is [`get_grouped_opcodes`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_grouped_opcodes). It will return a generator, which generates lists with change descriptions.

I'll explain it on an example from a [random commit on GitHub](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/73adda414647c7ecbc16bd9a768a042ac2dcc41e). Let's say you run `SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).get_grouped_opcodes()` on the old and new file "tabs_events.js". The generator will generate two groups, which are represent by those "..." lines in GitHub. It's basically a group of changes. In each of the groups, you have a list of detailed changes stored as tuples. For the first group, it returns two changes that look like this (the first item is a change type, the next two numbers represent a line range to be removed, followed a line range to be added):

```
('replace', 24, 29, 24, 29)
('insert', 33, 33, 33, 35)
```

The first one tell you to replace lines 24-28 (starting with 0) from the old file with lines 24-28 from the new file. The second one tells you to insert lines 33-34 from the new file on  line 33 in the old file. I think it's clear what would `'delete'` do and `'equal'` are those lines that are not highlighted in GitHub.

If you don't mind reading source code, take a look at the implementation of [`difflib.unified_diff()`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release26-maint/Lib/difflib.py?revision=76468&view=markup). It's quite simple and it generates a plain-text equivalent of what you want.